# Python making a nested list from file text

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, nested-lists

The file contains the following text

```
2,3,2
2,2,2
2,9
```

I need to create a nested list such that it returns 
[[2,3,2],[2,2,2],[2,9]] but when ever I try to convert the string to an int an error comes up

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: the `int()` function only accepts numeric strings.  Try splitting each line using `line.split(',')` (where `line` is the line read from file) then passing each result to `int()`.

Comment: Thanks for using Stack Overflow. If you could edit your question to include code and whatever error you stuck on, we would be able to help. How can we otherwise!?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this out:

Let say your file name is test.txt

```
res = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        res.append(list(map(int, line.split(','))))

print(res)
```

Output:-

```
[[2,3,2],[2,2,2],[2,9]]
```